# Case is not getting created via Email-To-Case

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I have configured Email-to-case and when I send an email from test_1@email.com(for example)  to the service address the case is not getting created but when I send an email from test_2@email.com then case is getting created.

So why it is working for one email address and not for others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you send to some friendly mailbox like "customerservice@example.com" or to the long unreadable SF address like "customerservice@-randomrubbishhere.instance.case.salesforce.com"? Maybe the forwarding rule on your mail server (if any) forwards only certain messages.

What are your email-to-case settings. Maybe you allow only plaintext emails and no attachments and the 2nd message is sent as html or with attachments.

At the bottom of the Email-to-Case page there will be routing address (like my "customerservice@example.com"). In there there's tiny little field about ["accept email from"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizesupport_routing_address_settings.htm&type=5). Either keep the field blank or make sure both addresses are added?

Do you use standard Email-to-Case (basic stuff) or do you have an Apex class as inbound email handler? If Apex - you can set debug logging on the running user and see if it fails in code, on validation rule during insert or what.

EDIT, more things to check

Interesting.

Do you send both to same address? If to different ones and they're configured with diff. case record type - check in Setup -> Support Settings if Automated Case User has permission to all record types. If you have different record types and validation rules that depend on type and they can't pass if field isn't populated from email - that might be a problem

Did you get any error emails in that mailbox from support@salesforce.com? They might be in junk/spam folder

Can you put debug logging on that automated case user and see if anything pops up

Does the email have something that would fail to save like subject > 255 characters?

Go to Setup -> Monitor -> Email Snapshots and request a snapshot, maybe there's something interesting in there, maybe it doesn't arrive in SF at all and then you need to check the email server, forwarding rules...

Is it on Gmail? There might be an extra step in config, see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328923&type=1&mode=1

Comment: I have tested it for both mailbox and long service address. "Accept email from" field is blank. I am using standard out-of-box feature email-to-case.

Comment: No worries it is resolved now. One validation rule was getting fired. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure forwarding email address for your outlook or gmail account. For outlook below is the process:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/configure-email-forwarding?view=o365-worldwide

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My problem was that Gmail had marked the sender of the confirmation email as spam.

Comment: "as s"... "spam"?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure what happened to the rest if the word Spam! 

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35367411)